# What's the Node.js equivelent of the PHP hash function (including salt and raw output)?

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, authentication, encryption

My co-worker has a database that stores account information; an account's SHA256 hashed password and salt value are stored in columns as raw binary data (blobs).

The password is hashed in PHP using this (true indicates raw output):

```
hash("sha256", $salt . $password, true);
```

I'm trying to implement authentication on a Node.js server that has to get back the same hashed password that's stored in the database from PHP, this doesn't seem to work:

```
/**
 * Validates a password sent by an end user by comparing it to the 
 * hashed password stored in the database. Uses the Node.js crypto library.
 *
 * @param password The password sent by the end user.
 * @param dbPassword The hashed password stored in the database.
 * @param dbSalt The encryption salt stored in the database.
 */
function validatePassword(password, dbPassword, dbSalt) {
    // Should the dbSalt be a Buffer, hex, base64, or what?
    var hmac = crypto.createHmac("SHA256", dbSalt);
    var hashed = hmac.update(password).digest('base64');
    console.log("Hashed user password: " + hashed);
    console.log("Database password: " + dbPassword.toString('base64'));
    return hashed === dbPassword;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a lot of experimentation, I found a solution.

```
/**
 * Encrypts a password using sha256 and a salt value.
 *
 * @param password The password to hash.
 * @param salt The salt value to hash with.
 */
function SHA256Encrypt(password, salt) {
    var saltedpassword = salt + password;
    var sha256 = crypto.createHash('sha256');
    sha256.update(saltedpassword);
    return sha256.digest('base64');
}

/**
 * Validates a password sent by an end user by comparing it to the
 * hashed password stored in the database.
 *
 * @param password The password sent by the end user.
 * @param dbPassword The hashed password stored in the database, encoded in Base64.
 * @param dbSalt The encryption salt stored in the database. This should be a raw blob.
 */
function validatePassword(password, dbPassword, dbSalt) {
    var hashed = SHA256Encrypt(password, dbSalt.toString('binary'));
    return hashed === dbPassword;
}
```

Thanks to TravisO, though, he put me on the right path.

Comment: Please **DO NOT** use SHA hashes to store passwords. You should be using something designed specifically for passwords like [bcrypt](http://codetheory.in/using-the-node-js-bcrypt-module-to-hash-and-safely-store-passwords/). It is possible to burn through billions of SHA256 encoded passwords per second. Salting helps, but a lot less than you'd think. If you're meshing with an existing PHP app, you're kind of stuck, but even PHP supports bcrypt.

Comment: It's not my choice, and it's too late to change it. The PHP has already been written by someone else and it's massive.

Answer (score 2):

crypto.createHash()

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.18/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhash_algorithm

Just make absolutely sure you use exactly the same hashing type, and salt.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this didn't complete solve the problem but it put me on the right path and I posted a solution below.